# .NET Regex Expression For Finding & Replacing Any ProductName Value In A .vdproj File In C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vdproj

I'm trying to write a NAnt extension task that can update different settings within a Visual Studio 2003 generated Setup .vdproj file, and would appreciate help with the following.

Specifically, I would like to use a RegEx expression to find, and if found, replace any value string value assigned to the ProductName value with a new string value in its entirty.

I am looking for a RegEx expression set to change "ProductName" to any other value without having to rely on anything other than that the string sought begins with "ProductName" = "8": and then has 1 or more characters and ends with a " mark.  I've tried the following to no avail:

Before executing the following code fragment, the .vdproj file's ProductName reads:

```
"ProductName" = "8:My Simple .NET Application"
```

... and the code fragment in C#:

```
string _theProductName = "My Other Native Application";

Regex productNameExpression = new Regex( @"(?:\""ProductName\"" = \""8:*)" );

_theProjectFileContents = 
productNameExpression.Replace(_theProjectFileContents, 
                              "\"ProductName\" = \"8:" + _theProductName + "\"" );

bool updatedProductName = 
(_theProjectFileContents.IndexOf(_theProductName) >= 0);
```

After executing the above code fragment, the .vdproj file's ProductName now reads:

```
"ProductName" = "8:My Simple .NET Application"My Other Native Application"
```

Close, but I was expecting "My Other Native Application" to replace "My Simple .NET Application", and not add to it.

Any insights and help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very nearly there - only missing a single .
Change your regex thus and happiness should follow...

```
Regex productNameExpression = new Regex(@"(?:\""ProductName\"" = \""8:.*)");
```

Note the . after the 8:

Comment: Hi, Dan:

Indeed, happiness did follow.  Moreover, the same Regex expression definition worked for the Title and ARPCOMMENT/Description properties inside the .vdproj file as well.

Again, many thanks for your time and help...